# Parenthesis error on my assign command for my output (dataflow level)

Tags: verilog, modelsim

```
assign    F=((A&B)(~|)(C|D))^((C|D)(~&)((~)A(~|)C));
```

I have no idea why I get this error:

> Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/JsnK/Desktop/New
>   folder/circuit1_dataflowlvl.v(6): near "(": syntax error, unexpected
>   '('.

Here is a schematic : http://prntscr.com/ld9n7a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the inversions outside of the parentheses:

```
assign F = ~((A&B) | (C|D)) ^ ~((C|D) & ~( ~A | C));
```